# Как вставить текст в картинку пропорционально его ширине

Tags: python, pil

Есть изображение `x,y`
Я увеличиваю его на `x+100,y+100.`

Стоит задача наверху увеличенной картинки сделать описание.
Я середину нашёл, и текст тоже вставил. Но он очень маленький. Как увеличить его пропорционально ширине?

```
def resize_canvas(old_image_path, new_image_path):

    im = Image.open(old_image_path)
    old_width, old_height = im.size

    canvas_width = old_width+100
    canvas_height = old_height+100
    x1 = int(math.floor((canvas_width - old_width) / 2))
    y1 = int(math.floor((canvas_height - old_height) / 2))

    mode = im.mode
    if len(mode) == 1:  # L, 1
        new_background = (255)
    if len(mode) == 3:  # RGB
        new_background = (255, 255, 255)
    if len(mode) == 4:  # RGBA, CMYK
        new_background = (255, 255, 255, 255)

    newImage = Image.new(mode, (canvas_width, canvas_height), new_background)
    newImage.paste(im, (x1, y1, x1 + old_width, y1 + old_height))
    msg = "hello"
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newImage)
    xy = ((canvas_width/2),0) 
    draw.text(xy, msg, fill="black")
    newImage.save(new_image_path)
```

Comment: Укажите шрифт с размером: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/pil_pillow__examples/draw%20watermark/main.py#L22

Comment: а я рисую шаблон в svg, а потом перегоняю в растр через cairosvg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод вставляет текст в картинку строго по середине.

```
def resize_canvas(old_image_path, msg):

    im = Image.open(old_image_path)
    old_width, old_height = im.size

    canvas_width = old_width+100
    canvas_height = old_height+100
    x1 = int(math.floor((canvas_width - old_width) / 2))
    y1 = int(math.floor((canvas_height - old_height) / 2))

    mode = im.mode
    if len(mode) == 1:  # L, 1
        new_background = (255)
    if len(mode) == 3:  # RGB
        new_background = (255, 255, 255)
    if len(mode) == 4:  # RGBA, CMYK
        new_background = (255, 255, 255, 255)

    newImage = Image.new(mode, (canvas_width, canvas_height), new_background)
    newImage.paste(im, (x1, y1, x1 + old_width, y1 + old_height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newImage)

    font = ImageFont.truetype("18888.ttf", 50)

    width_text, height_text = font.getsize(msg)

    w, h = draw.textsize(msg, font=font)
    xy = (((canvas_width-w)/2),5) 

    draw.text(xy, msg, font=font,fill="black")
    newImage.save(old_image_path)
```